# Adding external libs to the Phalcon project

Tags: php, phalcon, lib

Cannot add the Phalcon mailer and use it in the project. Doing same as instructions say. I have config linking to `'libraryDir' => APP_PATH . '/app/lib/'`, in the `lib` folder I have a `Mailer` folder where I put the `composer.json`.

I followed [THIS](https://github.com/phalcon-ext/mailer) but after using the `lib` in the Controller I've got

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\Ext\Mailer\Manager'

Code :

```
use Phalcon\Http\Response; 
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria; 
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query\BuilderInterface; 
use Phalcon\Di\InjectionAwareInterface; 
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset; use Phalcon\Ext\Mailer\Manager; 
use Phalcon\Ext\Mailer\Message;

class EmailController extends Phalcon\Mvc\Controller { 
public function initialize() { 
if ($this->request->isPost()) { 
$this->view->disable(); 
} 
}
public function indexAction() {

}

public function sendEmailAction(){
    if ($this->request->isPost()) {

        $config = [
            'driver'   => 'mail',
            'from'         => [
                'email' => 'manager@email.com',
                'name'    => 'Email'
            ]
        ];

        $email = new Phalcon\Ext\Mailer\Message($config);
        return "send";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@klay answer is right. I see they actually ask to create a composer.json on their README. But I do agree to use [composer require](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) instead:

```
composer require "phalcon-ext/mailer":"~2.1"
```

You can also use the [phalcon loader](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/loader) to register your autoload file while you register other things.

```
$loader = new Loader();
$loader->registerFiles('../vendor/autoload.php');
```

If you need more help, I'd suggest to read the [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow `Phalcon\Ext\Mailer` installation instructions. There is no instructions about putting somewhere `composer.json`. Just install this library using typical for the Composer way:

```
composer require "phalcon-ext/mailer":"~2.0"
```

The last thing you need: make sure that you are using Composer autoloader:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```